# Angular6 - Using service outside of constructor - error as undefined

Tags: angular, angular-services

getting error as service is undefined if it is called from a function outside of OnInit() or a constructor

Any help is appreciated.

the call to the function from scramble() function is giving error if code is uncommented.

Cannot read property 'getTripsByCriteria' of undefined

code is as follows

```
export class UpcomingTripsComponent implements OnInit{
    private gridApi;
    title = "Upcoming Trips";
    trip_list: {};
    trips: UpcomingTripList;
    rowData: any;
    private gridColumnApi: any;
    last_hours: number = 1;
    next_hours: number = 4;
    msg: string ='';
    gridOptions: any;
    private headerHeight;
    private rowClassRules;
    private smallscreen: boolean = true;
    private firsttime: boolean = true;

constructor(private upcomingTripsService: UpcomingTripsService, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("last_hours")) {
        this.last_hours = Number(sessionStorage.getItem("last_hours"));
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("next_hours")) {
        this.next_hours = Number(sessionStorage.getItem("next_hours"));
    }
    this.headerHeight = 70;

    this.rowClassRules = {
        "interleaved-rows": function (params) {
            return (params.node.rowIndex % 2 !== 0);
        }
    };
    this.upcomingTripsService.getTripsByCriteria(this.last_hours, this.next_hours).subscribe(result => { //works here
        this.trips = JSON.parse(result.toString());
        this.rowData = this.trips.UpcomingTrips;
    }, error => console.error(error));

}
ngOnInit() {
    alert('in ngOnInit' + this.upcomingTripsService); //works
}

changeAutorefresh(event) {
    alert('in checkbox change');
    this.scrambleAndRefreshAll();
}
scrambleAndRefreshAll() {
    setInterval(this.scramble, 10000);
}
scramble(params: any) {
    alert('in scramble' + this.upcomingTripsService); //error

    //this.upcomingTripsService.getTripsByCriteria(this.last_hours, this.next_hours).subscribe(result => {
    //    this.trips = JSON.parse(result.toString());
    //    this.rowData = this.trips.UpcomingTrips;
    //}, error => console.error(error));
    var params1 = { force: true };
    this.gridApi.refreshCells(params1);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do that `this` is being (re)assigned to the `window` instead of the component instance. Use arrow functions to capture `this` when passing methods.

```
scrambleAndRefreshAll() {
    setInterval(() => this.scramble(), 10000);
}
```

or use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
scrambleAndRefreshAll() {
    setInterval(this.scramble.bind(this), 10000);
}
```

Comment: Made change but now the timer is not working, and not calling the function. No alert shown - alert('in scramble' + this.upcomingTripsService);

Comment: @coder - if you are having additional problems I recommend you create an [mcve]. I recommend using https://stackblitz.com and posting the link in your question.

Comment: @coder - also check the browser's development console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: It worked! thanks. needed to be build again..somehow ng build --watch wasnt working